# i don't know what is the error in my program the loop won't stop please check it

Tags: c, range, max, min

This program is designed to find the largest and the smallest number in the user input numbers then to print the range of the maximum and minimum number.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main ()
{
int n,max,min,i,j,k,l,m;
printf("please enter the number of numbers you wish to evaluate \n");
scanf(" %d",&n);
printf("please enter %d numbers \n",n);
for (i==1;i>=n;i++)
{
    scanf("%d",&j);
    max=0;
    min=0;
    if (j>max)
        j=max;
    else if (j<k)
        j=min;
    k=min;


}
printf("the max number is %d",&max);
for (l==max;l>=1;l--)
{

    printf("&d",l);
    printf(" ");
}
printf("the min number is %d",&min);
for (m==min;m>=1;m--)
{
    printf("\n &d",m);
    printf(" ");
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `for(i==1;...` should be `for(i=1;..`

Comment: and `i>=n` should be `i<=n`

Answer (score 0):

Check this out

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main ()
{

    int n, max, min, i, j;

    max = 0;
    min = 0;

    printf("please enter the number of numbers you wish to evaluate \n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("please enter %d numbers \n", n);

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &j);
        if (j[i] > max)
            max = j[i];
        if (j[i] < min)
            min = j [i];
    }

    printf("the max number is %d", &max);
    for (i = max; i >= 1; i--)
    {
        printf("&d",i);
        printf(" ");
    }

    printf("the min number is %d", &min);
    for (i = min; i >= 1; i--)
    {
        printf("\n &d",i);
        printf(" ");
    }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: identify the variable j

Comment: I missed the variable j declaration

Answer (score 0):

thank you I've edited the program and it worked just fine

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main ()
{
int n,max,min,i,j,k,l,m;
printf("please enter the number of numbers you wish to evaluate \n");
scanf("%d",&n);
printf("please enter %d numbers \n",n);
max=0;
min=0;
for (i=1;i<=n;i++)
{
    scanf("%d",&j);

    if (j>max)
        max=j;
    if (j<k)
        min=j;
    k=min;


}
printf("the max number is %d \n",max);
for (l=max;l>=1;l--)
{

    printf("%d \n",l);
    printf(" ");
}
printf("the min number is %d \n",min);
for (m=min;m>=1;m--)
{
    printf("\n %d",m);
    printf(" ");
}
return 0;
}
```